# (Stacked) Histogram with individually labeled observations

Tags: python, histogram

I am taking an university course based on Python and I need to build a histogram of the yearly returns for the last 100 years - so, I need to depict 100 observations. This is the [expected final result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QCwsg.png). So far, I managed to build a normal histogram, but I miss and have no clue how to proceed with are these horizontal borders for each observation.

I would be very grateful for any input from your side!

Thank you a lot!

Comment: Are you supposed to use a plotting library or draw the plot yourself? In the former case, you might be able to get to the result envisioned by exploiting stacked bar plots, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41296313/stacked-bar-chart-with-centered-labels or labeled heatmaps (with 'holes'), see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60454132/matplotlib-annotated-heatmaps-formatting